# xslt php select the first sibling and all its child nodes

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xpath

How does one select the first sibling of a xml node with all its child nodes and apply some transformations on it? So far I only succeeded in selected either the first sibling and only the first sibling (no child nodes that is) or everything following the xml node.

Say we have xhtml like this:

```
<div class="chapter">Chapter <span class="number">1.1</span> Lorum ipsum</div>
<h2 class="article">Article <span class="number">1.</span> Lorum ipsum</h2>
<p>Lorum ipsum</p>
```

And the result we are after is xml like this:

```
<chapter>
  <heading>
    <label>Chapter</chapter>
    <number>1.1</number>
    <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
  </heading>
  <article>
    <heading>
      <label>Article</chapter>
      <number>1.</number>
      <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
    </heading>
    <par>Lorum ipsum</par>
  </article>
</chapter>
```

My guess is that I need to do some regex magic to get the label and title tags right, but if this could also been done using plain xslt that would be great.

Comment: Sensible/correct nesting in the input would help *a lot* now. Is there a deeper reason why the `<div class="chapter">` does not enclose everything that belongs to it?

Comment: I know, the main reason is it is easier on the client part and that is a Good Thing (tm) ;) However just how much easier it is this way is open for some internal debate over here, must admit I'm more for better nesting.

Comment: How is *not* wrapping a bunch of elements that are logical unit in their own div easier on the client? What could this possibly break?

Comment: Client as in the people actually providing the original input. Since they are well paid lawyers, the less they have to do in their wysiwig editor, the better. Although as said I'm rather sceptic as to just how much easier it is this way...

Answer (score 1):

This XSLT 1.0 transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml"
>
  <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" />

  <!-- the identity template (copies all nodes verbatim, unless
       more specific templates implement different behavior) -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- start by applying templates to all chapter divs -->
  <xsl:template match="xhtml:html">
    <text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="xhtml:body/xhtml:div[@class='chapter']" />
    </text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- chapter div: generate heading, apply templates to adjacent h2 -->
  <xsl:template match="xhtml:div[@class='chapter']">
    <chapter>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="heading" />
      <!-- ... where the first preceding chapter div has the same ID -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="
        following-sibling::xhtml:h2[
          generate-id(preceding-sibling::xhtml:div[@class='chapter'][1])
          =
          generate-id(current())
        ]
      "/>
    </chapter>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- h2: generate heading, apply templates to adjacent paras -->
  <xsl:template match="xhtml:h2[@class='article']">
    <article>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="heading" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="
        following-sibling::xhtml:p[
          generate-id(preceding-sibling::xhtml:h2[@class='article'][1])
          =
          generate-id(current())
        ]
      "/>
    </article>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- headings follow the same scheme, so we can use a unified template -->
  <xsl:template match="xhtml:div | xhtml:h2" mode="heading">
    <heading>
      <label>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text()[1])" />
      </label>
      <number>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(xhtml:span[@class='number'])" />
      </number>
      <title>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text()[2])" />
      </title>
    </heading>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:p">
    <par>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </par>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <div class="chapter">Chapter <span class="number">1.1</span> Lorum ipsum</div>
    <h2 class="article">Article <span class="number">1.</span> Lorum ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorum ipsum A</p>
    <p>Lorum ipsum B</p>
    <h2 class="article">Article <span class="number">2.</span> Lorum ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorum ipsum D</p>
    <h2 class="article">Article <span class="number">3.</span> Lorum ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorum ipsum E</p>
    <p>Lorum ipsum F</p>
    <div class="chapter">Chapter <span class="number">2.1</span> Lorum ipsum</div>
    <h2 class="article">Article <span class="number">1.</span> Lorum ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorum ipsum G</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

yields:

```
<text>
  <chapter>
    <heading>
      <label>Chapter</label>
      <number>1.1</number>
      <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
    </heading>
    <article>
      <heading>
        <label>Article</label>
        <number>1.</number>
        <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
      </heading>
      <par>Lorum ipsum A</par>
      <par>Lorum ipsum B</par>
    </article>
    <article>
      <heading>
        <label>Article</label>
        <number>2.</number>
        <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
      </heading>
      <par>Lorum ipsum D</par>
    </article>
    <article>
      <heading>
        <label>Article</label>
        <number>3.</number>
        <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
      </heading>
      <par>Lorum ipsum E</par>
      <par>Lorum ipsum F</par>
    </article>
  </chapter>
  <chapter>
    <heading>
      <label>Chapter</label>
      <number>2.1</number>
      <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
    </heading>
    <article>
      <heading>
        <label>Article</label>
        <number>1.</number>
        <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
      </heading>
      <par>Lorum ipsum G</par>
    </article>
  </chapter>
</text>
```

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet creates the desired output:

```
<xsl:template match="html:div[@class='chapter']" mode="chapter">
    <xsl:element name="{@class}">
        <heading>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="chapter" />
        </heading>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::html:h2[generate-id(preceding-sibling::html:div[@class='chapter'][1])=generate-id(current())]" mode="chapter" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!--template for h2 in "chapter" mode, creates article content for the chapter-->
<xsl:template match="html:h2[@class='article']" mode="chapter">
    <xsl:element name="{@class}">
        <heading>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="chapter"/>
        </heading>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::html:p[generate-id(preceding-sibling::html:h2[@class='article'][1])=generate-id(current())]" mode="chapter" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::html:span[@class='number']]" mode="chapter">
    <label><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/></label>
</xsl:template>

<!--Generate an (number) element using the class attribute as the name of the element-->
<xsl:template match="html:span[@class='number']" mode="chapter">
    <xsl:element name="{@class}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!--title elements created for text nodes before the -->
<xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::html:span[@class='number']]" mode="chapter">
    <title><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/></title>
</xsl:template>

<!--Template in "chapter" mode, creates a par element inside the article-->
<xsl:template match="html:p" mode="chapter">
    <para><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/></para>
</xsl:template>

<!--prevent text from bleeding through in output-->
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="chapter"/>
```

Using [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak)'s example input XML, produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <chapter>
        <heading>
            <label>Chapter</label>
            <number>1.1</number>
            <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
        </heading>
        <article>
            <heading>
                <label>Article</label>
                <number>1.</number>
                <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
            </heading>
            <para>Lorum ipsum A</para>
            <para>Lorum ipsum B</para>
        </article>
        <article>
            <heading>
                <label>Article</label>
                <number>2.</number>
                <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
            </heading>
            <para>Lorum ipsum D</para>
        </article>
        <article>
            <heading>
                <label>Article</label>
                <number>3.</number>
                <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
            </heading>
            <para>Lorum ipsum E</para>
            <para>Lorum ipsum F</para>
        </article>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <heading>
            <label>Chapter</label>
            <number>2.1</number>
            <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
        </heading>
        <article>
            <heading>
                <label>Article</label>
                <number>1.</number>
                <title>Lorum ipsum</title>
            </heading>
            <para>Lorum ipsum G</para>
        </article>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

Comment: This is flawed, please test it with the XML I used.

Comment: @Tomalak: Aww snap. Of course you are right.  
I made improvements(borrowing from your answer) that correctly handle a full set of input with multiple chapters, articles, and paras(like your sample input has), rather than just the limited example from the question and made adjustments for XHTML namespace.

Comment: Thank you both very much! Now all I have to do is merge this with the xslt I already have, thanks again.

Comment: Hmm that was a little bit too quick :( The first example (Tomalak) seems to work  but only partially (most of the text in paragraphs and ul's is lost), the second one mostly doesn't do anything (seems like only the chapters and headings are matched) :( I must admit my example was perhaps a little bit oversimplified as the real xhtml contains a lot more different elements, but I just wanted to present the basic problem/question I had.